# Can you pass extra variables when rendering a collection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I've been using this pattern a lot in a recent project:

```
<%= render partial: 'path/to/partial', collection: @crowd, as: :person %>
```

What I'm wondering if it's possible to set another local variable using the same syntax (rather than eg falling back on an explicit `@crowd.each` loop), so that it would look something like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'path/to/partial', collection: @crowd, as: :person, day: 'Thursday' %>
```

(the above doesn't err, but just doesn't assign `day` in the relevant partial)

Comment: Try wrapping `day` in `locals` hash. `locals: { day: 'Thursday' }`

Comment: Try: `<%= render partial: 'path/to/partial', collection: @crowd, as: :person, locals: { day: 'Thursday' } %>`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `locals` for that:

```
render partial: 'some_partial', collection: @collection, as: :item_name, locals: { variable_name: 'value', other_variable: 123 }
```